# Passing parameters to Azure ARM templates

Tags: windows, powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have a template I'm using to deploy to a resource group which takes this parameter:

```
"envPrefixName": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Prefix for the environment (2-5 characters)"
  },
  "defaultValue": "cust1",
  "minLength": 2,
  "maxLength": 5
},
```

I would like to make this parameter a value that can be overriden when the cdmlet is called like such:

```
    $AzureParams = @{ 
        ResourceGroupName = $ResourceGroup
        TemplateUri = $TemplateUri
        TemplateParameterUri = $TemplateParamUri 
        Mode = "Complete"
        envPrefixName = "sunlb" #Override default parameter value
        Force = $true
    }

    New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment @AzureParams
```

I've tried this approach but the solution continues to try to use the value set in the template and not the one passed through as a parameter in my call.

EDIT: It is possible that the TemplateParameterUri file is causing and issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you supply the `TemplateParameterUri` it will use the parameters file to deploy the template (and take the value from the file) and your `envPrefixName` would get "lost" because it wont evaluate the parameters in the template.

Drop the `TemplateParameterUri` and it will work as you expect it (but you have to supply all the parameters in this case, unless they have default values)

Comment: Okay, I was thinking that might be the cause. That's kind of a problem what if there are stick params you want to provide through a param file but some things need to be more dynamic. Is that an unreasonable use case?

Comment: provide defaults in the template, not in the parameters file (can you even do that). Another option - edit the parameters file with powershell before the deployment

Comment: just to get you started: [here is the code](https://github.com/AvyanConsultingCorp/PCI_Reference_Architecture/blob/master/artifacts/module/private.ps1#L10) i'm using to modify parameters file. where `environmentReference` is the name of the parameter you are modifying

Comment: Oh okay, so instead of using the `-TemplateUri` you're pulling in the parameters file, modifying it to include the dynamic values you want to set, then using that in `New-AzureRMResourceGroupDeployment`

Comment: pretty much that

Comment: You can mix parameters-on-the-command-line with parameters-in-the-file if you use TemplateParameterFile. E.g. set some parameters in the file and some on the command line.  (Although I'm not familiar with rules about whether command line takes precedence if you set the same parameter in _both_ places). @4c74356b41 , are you saying that doesn't work if you use TemplateParameterUri?